# How to import variables into static resouce .js files?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, community, salesforcedx-cli, static-resources

**Example**

There are 3 .js scripts / files as a static resource.

First.js

Second.js

CommonVars.js

I am doing something like this in CommonVars.js

**CommonVars.js**

```
var myCommonVars = {
 NAME : 'STACK',
 LASTNAME : 'EXCHANGE',
 WORK : 'COOL WORK'
}
 export { myCommonVars };
```

**First.js**

```
 import {myCommonVars} from './CommonVars.js';
 alert( myCommonVars.NAME );
```

**Second.js**

```
 import {myCommonVars} from './CommonVars.js';
 alert( myCommonVars.NAME );
```

On a load of the script of file they are giving me error as :

```
 cannot use import statement outside a module salesforce
```

What should I do? Can I use this way to use common variables or what can be the way to keep some common attributes/properties in a separate .js file?

Comment: If you want to use import/export statements, you can write a [service component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/lightning-web-components-service-components).

Answer (score 1):

In your JS file, just define whatever you'd like:

```
var myCommonVars = {
 NAME : 'STACK',
 LASTNAME : 'EXCHANGE',
 WORK : 'COOL WORK'
}
```

It's pretty typical to attach such variables to `window`:

```
window.myCommonVars = {
 NAME : 'STACK',
 LASTNAME : 'EXCHANGE',
 WORK : 'COOL WORK'
}
```

Then, in your code, you can access it directly:

```
import MYJSFILE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myJsFile';

...

connectedCallback() {
  loadScript(this, MYJSFILE).then(
    () => console.log(myCommonVars.NAME)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use-case is to use these static resources with ES6 modules in Visualforce, then this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/pchittum/es6-module-in-visualforce-page) should help you. Based on this repo, here is how your use case would look like

**CommonVars.js** remains the same. **First.js** can be refactored to

```js
import { myCommonVars } from './CommonVars.js';

export function showAlert(){
    alert(myCommonVars.NAME);
};
```

and then here is how you use these static resources in VF.

```html
<apex:page>
    
  <script type="module">
      import { showAlert } from '{!URLFOR($Resource.STATICRESOURCE, 'first.js')}';
       
      showAlert();
  </script>
 
</apex:page>
```

If you want to achieve the same using LWC, you can either do what [**@sfdcfox** suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/354039/87694), or you can create a web component with just the JS file, which holds the functions, variables that you want to reuse.

**service.js**

```js
export const myCommonVars = {
    NAME : 'STACK',
    LASTNAME : 'EXCHANGE',
    WORK : 'COOL WORK'
};
```

You can import this file into any other LWC. For example
**AnotherComponent.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import { myCommonVars } from  'c/service';

export default class AnotherComponent extends LightningElement {
    
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(myCommonVars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , But These are not web components. These are .js files or scripts stored in salesforce Static Resources. That's the point of concern.

Comment: Do you want to use these static resources in LWC?

Comment: @VivekMakkar I've edited the answer to better address your question. Please let me know if it helps or if you need more details.